# How can I write test case for KeyPress event in Selenium-WebDriver (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation, selenium-webdriver

I tried the following code,

```
element = driver.find_element(:id, 'textbox')
element.senk_keys "Hello"
element.send_keys :enter
```

This set "Hello" in the text box but "enter" key is not working.
Is there ant better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby you can use it like this
driver.action.send_keys(element, "Hello").send_keys(element, :return).perform

Comment: Already I fixed. So that I answered my own question. Anyway your answer too work. I accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
element = driver.find_element(:id, 'textbox')
element.senk_keys "Hello"
element.send_keys :return
```